# compare result with other table mysql

Tags: mysql, compare

I have 2 table I select and count compare item form 2 tables, also after compare I need to compute how many item contain in other table.

```
select 
    results.userid,
    results.amount,
    results.type,
    results.counting
from
    (SELECT 
        userid, amount, code, count(*) as counting
    FROM
        user_buys
    join star ON (amount >= min_amount)
    group by type
    HAVING amount >= 1000) as results
```

with table below

```
 userid   |amount     
----------------------
  1       |   1000        
  2       |   2000   
  3       |   5500    
  4       |   8200     
  5       |   200     
  6       |   1500 
  7       |   800
```

I need to sync with other table

```
 min_compare|  min_amount |   type
-----------------------------------
  2         |   1000      |    1star
  2         |   2000      |    2star
  3         |   5000      |    3star
  4         |   8000      |    4star
  5         |   9000      |    5star
  6         |   10000     |    6star
  7         |   11000     |    7star
```

because we have

```
5 item larger 1000 it contain => 1star
3 item larger 2000 it contain => 2star
2 item larger 5000 it contain => 3star
1 item larger 8000 it contain => 4star
```

my expected result

```
 rankin
--------
  1star           
  2star
  3star  
  4star
```

i have another question, count of number start relate to min_compare , if i add new buy with 11000 it must have less number with 7 to compute 7star

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: i need to show min star to max star for all amount with all user, aslo i update my question and add new table result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select
    star.type, star.min_amount, t.cnt, t.userids
from star
inner join (
    select  t1.type, count(t2.userid) as cnt, group_concat(t2.userid order by t2.userid) as userids
    from star t1
    inner join user_buys t2 on t1.min_amount <= t2.amount
    group by t1.type
) t on t.type = star.type
order by star.type
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a26db/8)

Comment: dear reno i have another question,please read end my question,i update it

Comment: @VahidAlvandi If you have another question, please ask again on SO. As so far, this query can make it, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    star.type, star.min_amount, t.cnt, t.userids
from star
inner join (
    select  t1.type, t1.min_compare, count(t2.userid) as cnt, group_concat(t2.userid order by t2.userid) as userids
    from star t1
    inner join user_buys t2 on t1.min_amount < t2.amount
    group by t1.type
    HAVING cnt >= t1.min_compare
) t on t.type = star.type
order by star.type
```