# sum price of childs in other table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I have two table one store data child and parent hierarchy and other paths and descendant

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| userid   |    parent  |    price  |
+----------+------------+------------
| 1        |    null    |      20   | 
| 2        |      1     |      20   | 
| 3        |      1     |      20   | 
| 4        |      2     |      20   | 
| 5        |      2     |      20   | 
| 6        |      3     |      20   | 
| 7        |      4     |      20   | 
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to get all userid with parent 1 then get descendant in other table and group by userid sum prices

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| ancestor_id | descendant_id | path_length |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|           1 |             1 |           0 |
|           1 |             2 |           1 |
|           1 |             3 |           1 |
|           1 |             4 |           2 |
|           1 |             5 |           2 |
|           1 |             6 |           2 |
|           1 |             7 |           3 |
|           2 |             2 |           0 |
|           2 |             4 |           1 |
|           2 |             5 |           1 |
|           2 |             7 |           2 |
|           3 |             3 |           0 |
|           3 |             6 |           1 |
|           4 |             4 |           0 |
|           4 |             7 |           1 |
|           5 |             5 |           0 |
|           6 |             6 |           0 |
|           7 |             7 |           0 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I have query it sum all childs together

```
select 
sum(b.price)

from webineh_prefix_nodes_paths_tmp a

    join webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp b on (b.userid = a.descendant_id)

where a.ancestor_id = 1
```

this work fine but total sum parent 1

I need to show bellow result for child direct (2,3)

```
 +----------+------------+-
    | userid   |    total   |
    +----------+------------+
    | 2        |    80      |
    | 3        |    40      |
    +----------+------------+
```

also in create sqlfiddle my question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9415ed/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select ancestor_id as userid, sum(b.price) as total
from webineh_prefix_nodes_paths_tmp a 
join webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp b 
on b.userid = a.descendant_id
where a.ancestor_id in (select userid from webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp where parent = 1)
group by ancestor_id
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

***Edited***

```
select ancestor_id as userid, sum(b.price) as total
from webineh_prefix_nodes_paths_tmp a 
join webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp b 
on b.userid = a.descendant_id
inner join webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp c
on a.ancestor_id = c.userid
and c.parent = 1
group by ancestor_id
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: @VahidAlvandi OK, let's use `JOIN`, check my ***edited*** answer please.

Comment: work fine, i need a book for tutorial mysql like you.. please Please introduce yourself

Comment: Wow, you want this [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html)?

Comment: nice ! , how i can combine this query with your answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37877231/6477873    second query have another table with ranking with your answer result

Comment: Not very clear what you said above. :-( @VahidAlvandi

Comment: i now create new question ... plesase follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220478/combine-two-query-in-mysql

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select sum(b.price) from webineh_prefix_nodes_paths_tmp a join webineh_prefix_nodes_tmp b on (b.userid = a.descendant_id) where a.ancestor_id in ( 1,2,3) GROUP by ancestor_id
```