# combine two query in mysql of other questions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, join

i have two query in three table

table 1 = hirarchey of price an users

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| userid   |    parent  |    price  |
+----------+------------+------------
| 1        |    null    |      20   | 
| 2        |      1     |      20   | 
| 3        |      1     |      20   | 
| 4        |      2     |      20   | 
| 5        |      2     |      20   | 
| 6        |      3     |      20   | 
| 7        |      4     |      20   | 
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to get all userid with parent 1 then get descendant in other table and group by userid sum prices

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| ancestor_id | descendant_id | path_length |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|           1 |             1 |           0 |
|           1 |             2 |           1 |
|           1 |             3 |           1 |
|           1 |             4 |           2 |
|           1 |             5 |           2 |
|           1 |             6 |           2 |
|           1 |             7 |           3 |
|           2 |             2 |           0 |
|           2 |             4 |           1 |
|           2 |             5 |           1 |
|           2 |             7 |           2 |
|           3 |             3 |           0 |
|           3 |             6 |           1 |
|           4 |             4 |           0 |
|           4 |             7 |           1 |
|           5 |             5 |           0 |
|           6 |             6 |           0 |
|           7 |             7 |           0 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9415ed/30 work fine for sum of price of decedent

also in have another table with compute the ranking of result previous  query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5de18/1

i need to combine two query very thanks

more info about second query in this link [compare result with other table mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875133/compare-result-with-other-table-mysql)

two query result work fine but second query read table user_buys , i will user_buys remove and get from first query

Comment: Please post your tables definition here. SQL Fiddle is good and all, but it's supposed to be an addition .

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875133/compare-result-with-other-table-mysql

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: two query result work fine but second query read table user_buys , i will user_buys remove and get from first query

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud, if you were to use a nested set model instead...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,price INT NOT NULL
,lft INT NOT NULL
,rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,20,1,14),
(2,20,2,9),
(3,20,10,13),
(4,20,3,6),
(5,20,7,8),
(6,20,11,12),
(7,20,4,5);

SELECT SUM(x.price) 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.lft < x.lft 
   AND y.rgt > x.rgt 
 WHERE y.id = 1;
+--------------+
| SUM(x.price) |
+--------------+
|          120 |
+--------------+
```

Comment: i dont need nested set model . very thanks.please help me to combine my querys